# Could anybody explain what is the term "proxied" or "proxying" mean in Vue/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have read some articles about proxy in Javascript, but still don't quite get it. Then I was trying to figure out how the vue works same term pop up. Someone can help me with that?

Update: I am referring to the Proxy API Vue used for reactivity.

Comment: It might depend a bit on the context. Can you give an example that you're thinking of?

Comment: A little more context is required here. Are you asking about networking technology, ie the [Webpack dev-server proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) or the [Proxy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which Vue uses for reactivity in its `data` properties?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

Comment: You can also check out this guide to JavaScript's built-in `Proxy` object: https://javascript.info/proxy

Comment: I think I was confused about the Proxy API vue used for reactivity. Sorry for not making it clear earlier. Just curious about how vue achieves this behind the scene.

Answer (score 4):

So a proxy is literally a stand-in or replacement. Before computers, someone could be your proxy for a committee meeting. They stood in for you, and got your vote. In IT, you can have proxy servers that 'replace' the origin server, then forward calls to it, or proxy objects that stand in for some other object. IT pioneered, I think, proxy as a verb: to proxy, proxied, proxying, but the concept is the same.

The most common Vue-specific example is perhaps where the vue instance proxies, (stands in for, or exposes) the objects registered in it's `$data`. It's all explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data).

Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Proxying refers to having a intermediate web server running (express for instance) that can intercept the HTTP requests you make and forward them to another server. this allows you to get around cross origin resource sharing issues, especially in development mode.

Comment: _"Proxy"_ is not only limited to networking technology

Comment: no he doesnt mean that Proxy he mean this proxy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: @Ifaruki I think the point is that due to the lack of context we cannot be sure what is meant